# What is the maximum number of collisions that may result from hashing n keys?

Tags: hashtable

Would it be n, or n-1? In my head I believe it should b n-1, because the first item you insert has nothing to collide with, and any other item you insert can collide with all items before it possibly but not itself. Am I correct in thinking this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an empty set, it's quite difficult to explain how the first item you put in succeeds in colliding with something else. That said, if you consider a collision list (items having the same hash) you see that it contains `M` items that collide each with the other. Thus you have indeed `N-1` collisions while inserting the items, but `N` colliding items, for none of them is the "right" one.